# preg_match_all html tag except tags in double or single quotes

Tags: php, html, regex, pcre

Given this DOM

```
$html=<<<'EOD'
<div class='container clickable' data-param='{"footer":"<div>Bye</div>","info":"We win"}'>
 <img src='a.jpg' />
</div>
<a href='a.html'>The A</a>
<span></span>
<span data-span-param='{"detailTag":"<span class=\"link\">Anything here</span>"}'>
 <a></a>
</span>  
EOD;
```

I am trying to preg_match_all html tags with using this expression:

```
$tags = array();
if(preg_match_all('~<\s*[\w]+[^>]*>|<\s*/\s*[\w]+\s*>~im',$html,$matchall,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
   foreach($matchall as $m){
       $tags[] = $m[0];
   }
}  
print_r($tags);
```

The output of this expression is:

> Array
>       (
>        [0] => < div class='container clickable' data-param='{"footer":"< div>
>        [1] => < /div>
>        [2] => < img src='a.jpg' />
>        [3] => < /div>
>        [4] => < a href='a.html'>
>        [5] => < /a>
>        [6] => < span>
>        [7] => < /span>
>        [8] => < span data-span-param='{"detailTag":"< span class=\"link\">
>        [9] => < /span>
>        [10] => < a>
>        [11] => < /a>
>        [12] => < /span>
>       )

My expected output is this:

> Array
>       (
>        [0] => < div class='container clickable' data-param='{"footer":"< div>Bye< /div>","info":"We win"}'>
>        [1] => < img src='a.jpg' />
>        [2] => < /div>
>        [3] => < a href='a.html'>
>        [4] => < /a>
>        [5] => < span>
>        [6] => < /span>
>        [7] => < span data-span-param='{"detailTag":"< span class=\"link\">Anything here< /span>"}'>
>        [8] => < a>
>        [9] => < /a>
>        [10] => < /span>
>       )

I need a help with an expression to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you considered ***not*** using a regex and instead using a DOM parser?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: i've solved the problem and it's working. see my answer below.

Comment: @user5634507. My [fiddle](http://ideone.com/cPQOA6) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this problem is to use recursive regular expression.

```
(?!<\s*>)\<(?:(?>[^<>]+)|(?R))*\>
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/16hW3Z)

Answer (score 1):

This will match all html tags and will not capture tags enclosed in double or single quotes

```
<?php
$html=<<<EOD
<div class='container clickable' data-param='{"footer"<div>Bye</div>","info":"We win"}'>
<img src='a.jpg' />
</div>
<a href='a.html'>The A</a>
<span></span>
<span data-span-param='{"detailTag":"<span class=\"link\">Anything here</span>"}'>
<a></a>
</span>
EOD;

$html = preg_replace('~\&lt\;~is','<',$html);
$html = preg_replace('~\&gt\;~is','>',$html);
//$html = preg_replace('~\&quot\;~is','"',$html);
$html = preg_replace('~=\s*\'\s*\'~is','=\'.\'',$html);
$html = preg_replace('~=\s*"\s*"~is','="."',$html);

if(preg_match_all('~((?<==\')(?:.(?!\'))*.)\'|((?<==")(?:.(?!"))*.)"~im',$html,$matchall,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
  foreach($matchall as $m){
    if(preg_match('~\<~is',$m[0],$mtch1)||preg_match('~\>~is',$m[0],$mtch2)){
        $end = $m[0][(strlen($m[0])-1)];
        $replace1 = substr($m[0],0,(strlen($m[0])-1));
        $replace = preg_replace('~"~is','&quot;',$replace1);
        $replace = preg_replace('~<~is','&lt;',$replace);
        $replace = preg_replace('~>~is','&gt;',$replace);
        $html = preg_replace("~".preg_quote(($end.$replace1.$end),'~')."~is",$end.$replace.$end,$html);
    }
  }
}

$tags = array();
if(preg_match_all('~<\s*[\w]+[^>]*>|<\s*/\s*[\w]+\s*>~im',$html,$matchall,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
  foreach($matchall as $m){ 
    $tags[] = $m[0];
  }
}

print_r($tags);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array  
(  
[0] => <div class='container clickable' data-param='{&quot;footer&quot;:&quot;&lt;div&gt;Bye&lt;/div&gt;&quot;,&quot;info&quot;:&quot;We win&quot;}'>  
[1] => <img src='a.jpg' />  
[2] => </div>  
[3] => <a href='a.html'>  
[4] => </a>  
[5] => <span>  
[6] => </span>  
[7] => <span data-span-param='{&quot;detailTag&quot;:&quot;&lt;span class=\&quot;link\&quot;&gt;Anything here&lt;/span&gt;&quot;}'>  
[8] => <a>
[9] => </a>  
[10] => </span>  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works in your code, no additional code required:

```
<\s*(?:/\s*)?\w++(?>[^>'"]++|'[^']+'|"[^"]+")*>
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ijuzcF)

Comment: thanks @Alan, this is awesome, i'm going to use this expression in my code.